# Renomear arquivos recursivamente segundo padrão determinado em comandos Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script

Estou tentando renomear arquivos fazendo as substituição conformes padrões determinados, porem, queria fazer este trabalho recursivamente e ainda não consegui.

-/doc
|----- texto1.txt
|----- texto2.txt
|--/doc2 
**_|----- texto1.txt

_**|----- texto2.txt

Segue meu

```
#!/bin/bash
#padrao = $1
#substitui = $2

ls | rename "s/$1/$2/g"
```

Este script renomeia bem o que eu quero modificar, porem somente na pasta solicitada, tentei o "ls - R" porem não deu certo para fazer a substituição tambem nas pasta(diretorios) internos a pasta solicitada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substitui o ls pelo find, ele irá trazer a lista de arquivos e sub-arquivos. Algo como:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | rename "s/$1/$2/g"
```

O ponto traz o diretório local, mas você pode substituir até por outros diretórios, ex:

```
find /home/diretorio_de_usuario -name "*.txt" | rename "s/$1/$2/g"
```

Comment: Vlw, Lucas Polo. Verifiquei aqui é bem o que eu precisava.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um script para renomear arquivos de captura de tela que apareciam no DESKTOP:
`image.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop/
j=0
IFS="\n"
for i in `ls *.png`
do
  j=$(($j+1))
    if [ ! -e $1"$j".png ] ; then
      mv $i $1"$j".png
    else
    continue
    fi
done
cd -
```

Como funciona o script?

> 1. Você roda o script fornecendo um argumento que será o prefixo dos nomes.
>    Ex:  `$ sh image.sh <prefixo>` .
>
> Saída do comando:
>
> `prefixo1.png, prefixo2.png, etc...`
>
> 2. O script foi projetado para listar imagens `.png`, mas isso pode ser modificado colocando para ser informação passada pela linha de comando com argumento.
> 3. Caso novas imagens sejam inseridas no diretório ele passará a renomear a partir da ultima parada.

Sugiro que se faça algum script complementar para aplicar o código acima em cada diretório existente. Poderia ser: `$ find . -type d` que listará todos os diretórios de onde se está. O comando `xargs` pode ser muito útil para manipular a saída do find.

Existem infinitas possibilidades!

Espero ter ajudado!